# SQLite prepared Statement not working on SQLiteDateReader?

Tags: c#, sqlite, prepared-statement

Here is my code

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=userData.dat;version=3;");
connection.Open();

SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags_tags LIKE '%@tags_tags%' ORDER by tags_id DESC LIMIT 0, 100";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tags_tags", DbType.String);
cmd.Parameters["@tags_tags"].Value = tags;


SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var _sql = cmd.CommandText;
MessageBox.Show(_sql);//still shows "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tags_tags LIKE '%@tags_tags%' ORDER by tags_id DESC LIMIT 0, 100"
```

I also used `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` but not worked...
Where is the mistake?

Comment: have you try-catch any exception?

Comment: There is no any error. The only thing is that my query still is not prepared

Comment: You cannot see the complete query with replaced variables in command text. You have to start SQL Profiler and log the query sent to the server. There you will have the exact same query but also the defined Variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

concatenate the parameter in your string, eg

```
LIKE '%' || @tags_tags || '%'
```

you are enclosing the parameter with single quotes, thus making it a value. remove the single quotes and concatenate the percent symbol on the value of the parameter.

```
LIKE @tags_tags
```

and in your parameters,

```
cmd.Parameters["@tags_tags"].Value = '%' + tags + '%';
```

Comment: Really really really nice! This is exactly what I want :x